# How can I stop the grey tint that covers the viewport when I'm using edit mode?

Tags: 3d-view

Whenever I enter edit mode on my scene, a greyish tint is applied over the entire viewport until I go back to object mode. How can I disable this effect for edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

Disregard, I had to unset 'fade inactive geometry' under the 'show overlays' dropdown menu.